# Estimating Power and Energy Consumption of a Spiking Neural Network

Tags: power, cpu

I have a traditional Convolutional Neural Network (CNN), and I've converted that to a Spiking CNN (S-CNN). I wanted to compare them on the basis of power and energy consumption. By using a different software (Nengo), I got the energy consumption of the CNN on CPU, but for the spiking network, I got the energy consumption (J per inference) on Neuromorphic Hardware (Loihi). However, I want to obtain the **energy consumption of the Spiking Network on CPU as well**. I have the following parameters known exactly:

- CNN energy consumption(CPU): 6.94 mJ/inference, CNN runtime(CPU): **16
  ms**, CNN operations: **0.85*10^6 MACs** (Multiply and Accumulate
  Operations).
- S-CNN runtime(CPU): **30 ms**, S-CNN operations: **1.6*10^6 ACCs**
  (Only    Accumulate Operations).

Is there a way to estimate the energy consumption of the S-CNN on CPU using these parameters? I remember reading somewhere (Can't find the source now) that Multiply and Accumulate and Accumulate operations have the same power consumption. So, the S-CNN will consume (1.6/0.85)*(30/16) ~ 3.5 times more energy on CPU.

Is there any other way to do this estimation? A crude estimation will also do.

Comment: I would expect multiply-accumulate to use more energy than accumulate since you're doing an additional multiply operation which is relatively complex.   The easiest way to find this out would be to measure it on the specific device.  Estimation from operation counts will have huge uncertainty due to the effect of memory accesses.

Comment: Is there a source which I can check out for the ratio of the energy costs of these operations? On an Intel Xeon CPU

Comment: That ratio is going to vary a lot depending on how you use the instructions, so not meaningful even if you could find it.  If your code is not well optimized, probably reasonable to just ignore the differences and assume all operations use the same energy.